# Query: Using Ethernet cable from phone jacks for internet

Tags: networking, ethernet, dsl, rj-11

I'm currently using a 100mbps FTTN internet connection. The distribution box at home has 2 phone jacks (Photo A) feeding 2 RJ11 cables (3 feet each) into the modem's DSL 1 and 2 ports. 
The modem/router supports a WAN and 4 Ethernet ports.

[Photo A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c68WG.jpg)

The internet technician advised to connect 2 phone lines for better speeds - and I am getting the speeds as promised. Individually a single phone line was no where near desired speeds. I do not have phones in use.

Currently in a wireless setup. The issue is poor wireless signals around the house. The objective is to replace the RJ11 cables with preferably a 15 meter CAT6 cable to relocate the router to a better location and thus connect my PC via Ethernet as opposed to wireless.

1. Is it possible to splice an Ethernet cable to 2 phone jacks to plug into the WAN port on the router?
2. If not, what is my other option for relocating the router - invest in longer HQ shielded RJ11 cables to achieve distance?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1) No. you’re talking about completely different technology.

Option 2) Yes. Just hook up longer wires.

Comment: Then, is it possible to combine both phone lines into 1 RJ 11 cable to plug into the router/modem in just 1 DSL slot? I ask because I just found an existing RJ11 cable with 4 wires attached to it tucked inside the drywall. This is the desired length/location - I suspect the previous tenants left this behind. I'm sure I can trace it back to the distribution box.

Comment: @eszed Each DSL line should consist of two wires. Theoretically you could connect each line to a single pair in the 4 wire cable. Then you would split it back out in to two jacks at the other end to plug in to each DSL port. The only problem I see if potential cross-talk in the wires which will reduce bandwidth. You’d have to test that one.

Comment: forgive me but why would I need to split it back out in 2? If I were to connect 4 wires from the phone jacks at the distribution box to essentially make a 4 wire / 2 pair RJ11, could I not just plug that into the DSL router/modem's 1 port?

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative. PowerLine - run ethernet over the power circuits.

So you leave the router where it is, use an ethernet cable to connect one of its ethernet ports to a PowerLine adapter in a nearby power socket, and then you locate another PowerLine adapter in a power socket close to your PC and connect that to your PC with another ethernet cable.

Effectively you just use your home's power circuits as a replacement for a long ethernet cable - connect your PC via ethernet - and avoid relocating your router.

I use exactly this setup in my home. I've disabled the wireless on the router, which, because it's close to the phone master socket, isn't in a good place to broadcast a good wireless signal. I then use PowerLine to provided wired ethernet to my office, where I wire a high-speed switch into the PowerLine adapter so I can connect my PC directly by ethernet and also connect a wireless access point that covers the whole house. You can get PowerLine adapters with multiple ethernet ports, so you could avoid the switch, and you can get pass-through adapters so you can still plug a powered device into the power socket as well as the PowerLine adapter itself.

More details on PowerLine [here](http://www.techradar.com/news/networking/powerline-networking-what-you-need-to-know-930691)

Comment: Thanks, I did read about powerline adapters during my research. So basically I am unable to add an Ethernet connection through my phone jacks. I do have a WiFi range extender (that solves my wireless range issues to an extent) that has an Ethernet port and I also have an older Linksys (only 2.4GHz) router with a WAN port. Can I configure these items somehow to increase 2.4GHz range and hardwire my PC?

Comment: @eszed, there are also phone line adapters (HomePNA standard), similar to powerline adapters (these use the existing telephone wiring for Ethernet connection).  They can get up to 320 Mbps. http://www.homepna.org/products/member_products/.  They work simultaneously with other use of the phone line (e.g., telephone or DSL connection).